# HTML input type date format

Tags: html, date, datepicker, format, date-formatting

I have an web application where I use an `<input type="date" id="dtNga" name="dtFrom" class="form-control" required>`. On my mobile it appears as **dd/MM/yyyy**, but on my testers mobile it appears as **MM/dd/yyyy**. It looks like it appears depending on mobile system local settings.

It is a way to show on all devices a standart date specified by my, not by their local settings? I want to be as **dd/MM/yyyy** on all devices.

Comment: Seems impossible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Comment: @Chaska I saw it but I thought maybe it can be done using some external library, or maybe after 7 years after this question is done, this may have change.